# validation of expiry time of access token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Application is multi tenant application. We have implemented custom validation setting ValidateIssuer = false, ValidateAudience = false,ValidateLifetime = false
We have extended JwtSecurityTokenHandler class, Is there a way to check Claims Expiry Token time like iat.

Answer (score 0):

Audience and lifetime validations are default validation logic in multi tenant application , you'd better enable ValidateAudience/ValidateLifetime in JwtSecurityTokenHandler , if you want to customize token lifetime validation logic , you could pass your own implementation of `TokenValidationParameters.LifetimeValidator` to achieve that.

The access token is a base 64 encoded JSON Web Token ([JWT](https://jwt.io/introduction/)) and its contents can be inspected by running it through a decoder. You could decode the access token and check the Not Before and Expiration Time(exp) claims  to verify that the token has not expired .Please refer to [Azure AD token reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims).